# traffic flow: red/green light or stop and move?

Tags: network-flow

I live in the burbs and every day twice I drive through a 4-way intersection (E/W - N/S) that is controlled by a red light at which one has to stop from all directions and may pass in the order of arrival. The lines are unbearably long in the morning and evening but almost no wait any other times. One has the feeling that the scheme is designed for the rich folks that do not have to go to work but live E/W (back road) and screw those that live N/S that travel the state road as I.

My question: would a normal red/(yellow)/green traffic light speed up the intersection for the hoi-polloi travelling N/S during work hours?

(Assume some ideal rate of arrivals, say, exponential at a 4-way intersection. Which gives  higher flow rate: a fixed time red/green light to control the traffic flow or all must stop and 1st to arrive to cross?)

Comment: This would depend on how much traffic is there, how long it takes to stop and then to start driving, etc.

Comment: ... and the time to clear the intersection.  It's a nice mathematical modelling problem, but more work is needed to identify and assign values to parameters to make it realistic.  If the intention is to have the Readers perform the entire modelling exercise, it tends to make the problem less about the mathematics (queuing theory) and more about the Readers' imaginative faculties.